# VSCode searching/find in current active file Ctrl+f popup stoped showing for some reason

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason ctrl+f shortcut stopped showing the find popup

[image]

thought a quick look at the web would result in quick solution but this is not the case.

clearly it has something to do with keymap override(of extension, user, or workspace).

went to keyboard shortcut

[image]

and searched for ctrl+f key binding but there are many that apply on different scenario and IM not sure which of them overrides Vscode's builtin ctrl+f search shortcut on active editor.

by the way it's happening only on my ssh WSL remote vs code instance(not sure if this is related)

EDIT: I solved it but because I could not find quick solution in the web I'm leaving this post so other could find it.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case i solved it by clicking on the little 'Open Keyboard Shourtcuts(JSON)' icon on the top right section.

[image]

it would bring up some 'user defined'(never remembering defining them) overrides.

[image]

I don't remember defining any of them!

deleted them:

[image]

now pressing ctrl+f perfectly popups that find in active file modal:

[image]